# find in datfarame outliers and fill with nan python

Tags: python, dataframe, function, outliers, fillna

I am trying to make a function to spot the columns with "100" in the header and replace all values in these columns that are above 100 with nan values :

```
import pandas as pd
    
data = {'first_100':  ['25', '1568200', '5'],
            'second_column': ['first_value', 'second_value', 'third_value'],
             'third_100':['89', '9', '589'],
            'fourth_column':['first_value', 'second_value', 'third_value'],
            }
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
```

[image]

so this is the output I am looking for

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to identify the columns with `'100'`, [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to ensure having numeric values, then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with a boolean array:

```
cols = df.filter(like='100').columns

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').gt(100))
```

output:

```
  first_100 second_column third_100 fourth_column
0        25   first_value        89   first_value
1       NaN  second_value         9  second_value
2         5   third_value       NaN   third_value
```